# Notify user if data they enter matches conditions

Tags: email-alert

first time poster and appreciate any suggested, even if its that this can't be done.

I have users entering data and sometimes, they do it wrong e.g. Putting future dates in "Actual dates" that can't have happened yet.

I have a set of reports that looks for those combinations and highlights them, and I can subscribe to them, so they are pointed out weekly, but I'd prefer a lower admin/more pro-active approach.

The reports all include the User, so I want all users listed in the report to be sent a copy of it.

Using reports might be a red herring, and in fact a different mechanic would be better like a flow, but I am a new user so my understanding is very limited

All suggestions greatly appreciated.
Thanks
GD

Comment: Do you want a warning to be shown or do you want to stop invalid data being saved altogether?

Comment: Hey Fred, thanks for the ideas, now have plan !

Answer (score 0):

Whenever possible, it's better to block invalid data from entering the system in the first place. This is what [Validation Rules](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.fields_about_field_validation.htm&type=5) are for. You can simply prevent a user from entering a future date.

For example:

```
ACTUAL_DATE__C > TODAY()
```

Would cause an error to display and not allow the user to continue until they correct their mistakes.

Aside from that, subscribers to a report are static and can't be changed automatically. The direct answer to your question is "no."

However, you could use the [Apex Scheduler](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm) to run periodically, use the [ReportManager](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_reports_reportmanager.htm) features to parse the report, and then email them using [Messaging](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_namespace_Messaging.htm).

Alternatively, as you said, a Flow can also accomplish this, but you wouldn't typically use a report, but rather just query the records you need with [Get Records](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_ref_elements_data_get.htm&type=5), [Loop](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_ref_elements_loop.htm&type=5) through the results to get the users you want to email, and then use [Send Email](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_ref_elements_actions_sendemail.htm&type=5) to notify those users. You can use the Scheduled Flow type to run this logic periodically.

Comment: Thank you for a really useful reply, your first paragraph has changed my approach… going to try and validation rules, hopefully find a way to put a message explain what’s needed.  Sorry for slow reply only just saw it.

Comment: @Natalie Yes, you can attach the error to a specific field, and the field will be highlighted with the message if the rule is triggered.

Comment: Great, time to play 